# Angular async pipe syntax

Tags: angular

Is there a way to factorize the

```
(places$ | async)
```

in

```
  <div *ngIf="(places$ | async) === undefined">Loading...</div>
  <div *ngIf="(places$ | async) === null">No data</div>
  <div *ngIf="(places$ | async) != null">{{ (places$ | async) }}</div>
```

I indeed store an array of places in my observable, and I need to check if the observable is either undefined or null or not empty.

Best regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use *ngIf to do as follow

i wrap it in {} to be sure we get data anyway and not be affected by ngIf

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ data: places$ | async} as source">
  <div *ngIf="source.data === undefined">Loading...</div>
  <div *ngIf="source.data === null">No data</div>
  <div *ngIf="source.data !== undefined && data !== null">{{ source.data }}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: "Loading..." is never displayed with your solution.

Comment: @alcfeoh it depends from source if we use new BehaviorSubject(undefined) it will, if we use Subject and do source.next(undefined) it also will show loading